# Updating Nested dictionary with new information in table/dictionary using update

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Given the following dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'AA':['THISISSCARY'],
         'BB':['AREYOUAFRAID'],
         'CC':['DONOTWORRY']}
```

I'd like to update the values in the dictionary given the information in the following table

```
Table = pd.DataFrame({'KEY':['AA','AA','BB','CC'],
                      'POSITION':[2,4,9,3],
                      'oldval':['I','I','A','O'],
                      'newval':['X','X','U','I']})
```

that looks like this

```
   KEY   POSITION  oldval  newval
0   AA         2      I      X
1   AA         4      I      X
2   BB         9      A      U
3   CC         3      O      I
```

The end result should look like this:

```
dict1 = {'AA':['THXSXSSCARY'],
         'BB':['AREYOUAFRUID'],
         'CC':['DONITWORRY']}
```

Essentially, I'm using the **KEY** and **POSITION** to find the location of the value in the dictionary then if the **oldvalue** matches the one in the dictionary, then replacing it with the **newval**

I've been looking at the update function where I'd convert my table to a dictionary but I'm unsure how to apply to my example.

Comment: I believe list indexes start with 0 in python. If I do the following  p = dict1['AA'] , then p[0][3]  will give 'S'

Comment: Yes, that was an error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First craft a nested Series/dictionary to map the key/position/newval, then use a dictionary comprehension:

```
s = (Table.groupby('KEY')
     .apply(lambda d: d.set_index('POSITION')['newval'].to_dict())
     )

out = {k: [''.join(s.get(k, {}).get(i, x) for i,x in enumerate(v[0]))]
       for k,v in dict1.items()
       }
```

Output:

```
{'AA': ['THXSXSSCARY'],
 'BB': ['AREYOUAFRUID'],
 'CC': ['DONITWORRY']}
```

Intermediate `s`:

```
KEY
AA    {2: 'X', 4: 'X'}
BB            {9: 'U'}
CC            {3: 'I'}
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for this response. If the dict values were only strings and not a list. Eg. 'AA' : 'THISISSCARY'. How can I apply this approach without doing something like converting such as" newdict = {k:list(v.split("-")) for k,v in dict1.items()}  ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
dict_df=Table.to_dict('records')
print(dict_df)
'''
[{'KEY': 'AA', 'POSITION': 2, 'oldval': 'I', 'newval': 'X'}, {'KEY': 'AA', 'POSITION': 4, 'oldval': 'I', 'newval': 'X'}, {'KEY': 'BB', 'POSITION': 9, 'oldval': 'A', 'newval': 'U'}, {'KEY': 'CC', 'POSITION': 3, 'oldval': 'O', 'newval': 'I'}]
'''

for i in list(dict1.keys()):
    for j in dict_df:
        if i == j['KEY']:
            mask=list(dict1[i][0])
            mask[j['POSITION']]=j['newval']
            dict1[i]=["".join(mask)]
print(dict1)
# {'AA': ['THXSXSSCARY'], 'BB': ['AREYOUAFRUID'], 'CC': ['DONITWORRY']}
```